# How to load blocks data into EditorJS?

Tags: editorjs

I want to load blocks data dynamically to my EditorJS instance.
I would like to do something like this:

```
const editor = new EditorJS();
editor.load({ blocks: my_blocks })
```

I do not seem to find any documentation on how to do it on https://editorjs.io/

I know that I can load blocks to EditorJS during initialization, but I need to load dynamic data on button click.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use the [Blocks Core API](https://editorjs.io/blocks#insert), by means of the `insert()` method, using the below signature:

```
 insert(type?: string, data?: BlockToolData, config?: ToolConfig, index?: number, needToFocus?: boolean): void
```

So, in your case, it could be:

```
editor.blocks.insert('header', {text: 'My header'});
```

Where `header` is the **type** and the second argument is the block `data`

A cleaner approach would be to pre-define your block as follows:

```
const blockToAdd = {
  type: 'header', 
  data: {
     text: 'My header'
  }
};

editor.blocks.insert(blockToAdd);
```

Comment: Thank you, that should work. So I need to add the blocks manually one by one if I understood correctly.

Comment: Indeed, but you could create a function and provide an array of blocks as argument, as follows: `function addBlocks(blocks) { for (var i of blocks) { editor.blocks.insert(i) } }`

Comment: Yes, of course. But we need to clean the existing blocks first.

Comment: I tried this way, but I got an error. You have to pass each property directly in the insert function as stated in https://stackoverflow.com/a/68949306/5199281

Answer (score 5):

Not sure when this was added to the API, but there is also `editor.render(data)` which loads JSON data into the editor dynamically.

> render(data: OutputData): Promise
> Method removes all Blocks and fills with new passed JSON data

Source: https://editorjs.io/blocks#render