# Getting an error when trying to add a new block to EditorJS manually

Tags: javascript, editorjs

## Context

I've created a two column page, one column with a button on the left and editorJS on the right column.

What I am trying to do is whenever I click on the button to the left, I want it to be copied into a new block of EditorJS.

## Replication

The error triggers whenever trying to add a new block manually (in this case, an extertal button to add more content to EditorJS) using `editor.blocks.insert(blockToAdd)`. Independently of the configuration of the EditorJS, even the most basic one will trigger this error.

## Code

index.js (I've modified this file to make it shorter, the error always trigger in the same place which is

```
const blockToAdd = {
    type: 'paragraph', 
    data: {
      text: 'My header'
    }
  };
editor.blocks.insert(blockToAdd); // Here
```

Actual file

```
const btn = document.getElementById('export-btn')

const editor = new EditorJS({
  /**
   * Id of Element that should contain Editor instance
   */
  onReady: () => {
    new DragDrop(editor);
  },
  holder: 'editorjs',
  tools: {
    header: {
      class: Header,
      config: {
        placeholder: 'Enter a header',
        levels: [1,2,3,4],
        defaultLevel: 3
      }
    },
    paragraph: {
      class: Paragraph,
      inlineToolbar: true,
    }

  },
});

function saveEditor() {
  editor.save().then( savedData => {
    fetch('http://localhost:3000', {
      method: 'POST',
      body: JSON.stringify(savedData),
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
      }
    }).then( msg => {
      console.log(msg)
    }).catch( err => {
      console.error(err)
    })
    console.log()
  })
  .catch( err => {
    console.error(err)
  })
}

btn.addEventListener('click', function() {
  const blockToAdd = {
    type: 'paragraph', 
    data: {
      text: 'My header'
    }
  };

  editor.blocks.insert(blockToAdd);
});
```

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <title>Testing EditorJS and Docx</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="col-left">
    <div id="export-btn" class="export-btn">Export to...</div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-right">
    <div id="editorjs"></div>
  </div>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@editorjs/editorjs@latest"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@editorjs/header@latest"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@editorjs/list@latest"></script>

 <script src="index.js"></script> 
</body>
</html>
```

## Error

```
Uncaught TypeError: can't access property "name", s is undefined
    S https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@editorjs/editorjs@latest:6
    value https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@editorjs/editorjs@latest:6
    value https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@editorjs/editorjs@latest:6
    <anonymous> https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@editorjs/editorjs@latest:6
    <anonymous> file:///E:/wdev/tasktag-dashboard-ui/index.js:105
    EventListener.handleEvent* file:///E:/wdev/tasktag-dashboard-ui/index.js:97
editorjs@latest:6:44399
```

[Error screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nidSD.png)

Where could the problem be at? Because I am using `<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/editorjs-drag-drop@latest"></script>` sort of imports?
Otherwise, I don't know what the problem is. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3):

So the problem was in the object I pass to the `editor.blocks.insert(blockToInsert)`.

It requires to pass option by option instead a single object. So the correct solution would be:

```
const blockToAdd = {
    type: 'paragraph', 
    data: {
      text: 'My header'
    }
  };

  editor.blocks.insert(blockToAdd.type, blockToAdd.data);
```

Thanks **Thomas** from a JavaScript Telegram community for helping me out to resolve this problem.